# Secondary x-Axis with different Labels & Ticks

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, twiny

I want to plot something with two x-axes. However the xticks don't align. Somehow the margins are ignored?! In the final version, the xlabels are different that means simply showing the axis at the top is not an option.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10.0, 4.0))
axs = fig.subplots(2, 2)

xticklabels = [str(x) for x in range(0, 40+1, 5)]
y = np.random.rand(41*8)
ax0 = axs[0,0].twiny()
axs[0,0].set_xticks(np.arange(0,41*8,5*8))
axs[0,0].set_xticklabels(xticklabels)
ax0.set_xlim(axs[0,0].get_xlim())
ax0.set_xticks(np.arange(0,41*8,5*8))
ax0.set_xticklabels(xticklabels)

axs[0,0].plot(y)

plt.show()
```

[image]

EDIT:
Actually I want to have something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10.0, 4.0))
axs = fig.subplots(2, 2)

xticklabels = [str(x) for x in range(0, 40+1, 5)]
y = np.random.rand(41*8)
ax0 = axs[0,0].twiny()
axs[0,0].set_xticks(np.arange(0,41*8,5*8))
axs[0,0].set_xticklabels(xticklabels)
ax0.set_xlim(axs[0,0].get_xlim())
ax0.set_xticks(np.arange(10*8,31*8,5*8))
ax0.set_xticklabels(["0", "25", "50", "75", "100"])

axs[0,0].plot(y)

plt.show()
```

[image]

But as you can see the ticks don't align. I'm getting crazy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to show a second x-axis (without plotting anything on it) it may be easier with a [secondary axis](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-secondary-axis-py). You'll have to change the [`functions`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.secondary_xaxis.html?highlight=secondary_x#matplotlib-axes-axes-secondary-xaxis) as needed:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

y = np.random.rand(41*8)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,41*8,5*8))
xticklabels = [str(x) for x in range(0, 41, 5)]
ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels)

secx = ax.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(lambda x: x/8, lambda x: x/8))

ax.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

I assume that the problem with `twiny` is due to the absence of data on the new Axes, but
I didn't manage to get it working, even after manually setting the data interval.

---

**Update as per comment and edited question**:

```
secx = ax.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(lambda x: 5*x/8-50, lambda x: 5*x/8-50))
secx.set_xticks([0,25,50,75,100])
secx.set_xticklabels([f'{x}' for x in secx.get_xticks()])
```

[image]

Comment: Does this work if I just want ticks/labels at 10-30 at the top axis?

Comment: yes, as I said you must just adopt the function: `functions=(lambda x: 10 + x/16, lambda x: 10 + x/16)`

Comment: Yes but I want only ticks at the top at the position 10-30 at the bottom with a different label: where 10 is at the bottom there should be 0 at the top and 100 at 30 with no other ticks. Sorry I just can't make it happen :(

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You may need to update your matplotlib to 3.2 or above.